# Updating json with lodash

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, lodash

Actually I need to handle mysite frontend fully with json objects(React and lodash).

I am getting the initial data via an ajax call we say,

```
starred[] //returns empty array from server
```

and am adding new json when user clicks on star buton it,

```
starred.push({'id':10,'starred':1});
```

if the user clicks again the starred should be 0

```
current_star=_findWhere(starred,{'id':10});
_.set(curren_star,'starred',0);
```

but when doing console.log

```
console.log(starred); //returns
[object{'id':10,'starred':0}]
```

but actually when it is repeated the global json is not updating,while am performing some other operations the json is like,

```
console.log(starred); //returns
[object{'id':10,'starred':1}]
```

How to update the global , i want  once i changed the json, it should be changed ever.Should I get any idea of suggesting some better frameworks to handle json much easier.

Thanks before!

Comment: are you using the underscore.js library? might be good to write that in the question

Comment: nope...its lodash.js

Comment: Could you add some more code please?

Comment: Well, this looks suspicious: `current_star=_findWhere(starred,{'id':10});`. Should be _.findWhere. Other than that, it should works since `_.findWhere` passes back a reference to the object in the array.

Comment: Hey  @Quy Am sorry if failed put a .(dot) over there.But i had that in my code.

Comment: If you want to update the global object , use assign - https://jsfiddle.net/pce35gr5/2/

Comment: @PrakashChokalingamC, I'm really having difficulty parsing your question. To begin with you are working with javascript objects, not json. Second, I'm not sure what you mean by global and not global. Can you provide a jsfiddle.net example perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working with arrays is complicated and usually messy. Creating an index with an object is usually much easier. You could try a basic state manager like the following:

```
// This is your "global" store. Could be in a file called store.js
// lodash/fp not necessary but it's what I always use.
// https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide
import { flow, get, set } from 'lodash/fp'

// Most basic store creator.
function createStore() {
  let state = {}
  return {
    get: path => get(path, state),
    set: (path, value) => { state = set(path, value, state) },
  }
}

// Create a new store instance. Only once per "app".
export const store = createStore()

// STARRED STATE HANDLERS
// Send it an id and get back the path where starred objects will be placed.
// Objects keyed with numbers can get confusing. Creating a string key.
const starPath = id => ['starred', `s_${id}`]
// Send it an id and fieldId and return back path where object will be placed.
const starField = (id, field) => starPath(id).concat(field)

// import to other files as needed
// Add or replace a star entry.
export const addStar = item => store.set(starPath(item.id), item)
// Get a star entry by id.
export const getStar = flow(starPath, store.get)
// Get all stars. Could wrap in _.values() if you want an array returned.
export const getStars = () => store.get('starred')
// Unstar by id. Sets 'starred' field to 0.
export const unStar = id => store.set(starField(id, 'starred'), 0)

// This could be in a different file.
// import { addStar, getStar, getStars } from './store'

console.log('all stars before any entries added:', getStars()) // => undefined

const newItem = { id: 10, starred: 1 }
addStar(newItem)
const star10a = getStar(10)
console.log('return newItem:', newItem === star10a) // => exact match true
console.log('star 10 after unstar:', star10a) // => { id: 10, starred: 1 }
console.log('all stars after new:', getStars())

// Each request of getStar(10) will return same object until it is edited.
const star10b = getStar(10)
console.log('return same object:', star10a === star10b) // => exact match true
console.log('return same object:', newItem === star10b) // => exact match true

unStar(10)
const star10c = getStar(10)
console.log('new object after mutate:', newItem !== star10c) // => no match true
console.log('star 10 after unstar:', getStar(10)) // => { id: 10, starred: 0 }
console.log('all stars after unstar:', getStars())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in mutating original state. 
Instead of making push, you need to do the following f.e.:

```
var state = {
    starred: []
};

//perform push
var newItem = {id:10, starred:1};
state.starred = state.starred.concat(newItem);

console.log(state.starred); 
//{ id: 10, starred: 1 }]

var newStarred = _.extend({}, state.starred);
var curr = _.findWhere(newStarred, {id: 10});

curr.starred = 0;

state = _.extend({}, state, {starred: newStarred});

console.log(state.starred)
//{ id: 10, starred: 0 }]
```

To solve this in a more nice looking fashion, you need to use either React's immutability helper, or ES6 stuff, like: {...state, {starred: []}} instead of extending new object every time. Or just use react-redux =)